# How can I get another application mainwindow coordinates and style in C#?

Tags: c#

How could I get in C# the main window coordinates (left, right, width, height) and main window state (maximized, normal,..) of a third-party application if I have the value of Process.MainWindowHandle for it (obtained from the session processes list)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need `GetWindowPlacement` WinAPI function. [Here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetWindowPlacement.html) you can find a great example.